# Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c++

In the project I have been working on, we have to send Cocoa notifications from C++ sub-projects to the main project above it. To do this we construct a map to act as a key-value store for the userInfo dictionary of the notification.

In one of the projects, the following code compiles just fine:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> *userInfo = new std::map<std::string, std::string>;
char buffer[255];

sprintf(buffer, "%i", intValue1);
userInfo->insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>("intValue1", std::string(buffer)));

sprintf(buffer, "%i", intValue2);
userInfo->insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>("intValue2", std::string(buffer)));

if(condition)
    userInfo->insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>("conditionalValue", "true"));

PostCocoaNotification("notificationName", *userInfo);
```

However, when this is copied into an identical file in another sub-project, the compiler throws the following on the userInfo->insert calls:

```
"Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'"
```

..and it cannot find the function for PostCocoaNotification:

```
No matching function for call to 'PostCocoaNotification'
```

Additionally, it throws the following errors in system headers:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_pair.h:73:11: Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_pair.h:74:11: Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_pair.h:73:11: Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_tree.h:1324:13: Cannot initialize a parameter of type '_Link_type' (aka '_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > *') with an rvalue of type '_Const_Link_type' (aka 'const _Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > *')
```

I've no idea what I've done to cause such chaos, especially when the code runs perfectly fine in another sub-project (successfully sending notifications). Any insight to the problem would be very welcome.

Comment: My first guess is that you need to include something. Possibly the header for pair ( utility ) or for string.

Comment: I would guess `string` too

Comment: I don't think the string header is the culprit, the line where userInfo is initialised (`std::map<std::string, std::string> *telemetry = new std::map<std::string, std::string>;`) does not throw any errors.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You need to include this header:

```
#include <string>
```

Comment: If that doesn't work please add:  `#include <fstream>`

Comment: #include <string> is sufficient.

Answer (score 47):

I got the same error trying to use the [`std::stringstream`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/) class. Add this header file:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
```

Comment: Can you explain how the `stringstream` class is relevant to the OP's question?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @AdrianMole It's relevant to a bunch of people who get the same error message

Comment: This resolved the error `error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::basic_stringstream<char>'`

Comment: Oh yes, just missing the header.